# Is it possible to use Perspective Data Grid in observablehq?

Tags: javascript, observablehq

I tried to use `Perpective` `Data Grid` in `observablehq`, but I am struggling to reproduce even the simpliest examples from the `Perspective` [documentation](https://perspective.finos.org/docs/js) such as the one below. I fear it is because I do not know how to import the modules. I tried `perspective = require("@finos/perspective")`, but it does not seem to be working. My end goal is to create a data exploration tool such as this [one](https://unpkg.com/@jpmorganchase/perspective-examples@0.2.0-beta.3/build/citibike.html).

```
<script>
    const worker = window.perspective.worker();
    const table = await worker.table({ A: [1, 2, 3] });
    const view = await table.view({ sort: [["A", "desc"]] });

    const viewer = document.createElement("perspective-viewer");
    viewer.load(table);
    document.body.appendChild(viewer);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the way this package seems to work is almost entirely incompatible with the way Observable works. It is essentially creating its own reactive data flow and injecting code and elements into the DOM, which ends up clashing with Observable's way of working.

Unless you specifically want to use this library, there are many examples of interactive exploration tools on Observable, though. Here's [one using a scatterplot](https://observablehq.com/@zzzev/pantry-nutrition-explorer) for example, or another [nice walkthrough using maps, tables, etc](https://observablehq.com/@bmschmidt/duckdb-degrees). And you can easily [find many more](https://observablehq.com/trending).

Comment: Are you sure it is not possible? I have seen notebooks that at least attempt to use perspectiveJS in observablehq. For example this one https://observablehq.com/@randomfractals/data-inspector

Comment: That example works for me once I upload a CSV in that input at the top; does it work for you? Is there a particular way in which it doesn't work?